# Confusion with Convergence in Distribution of Maximum of iid Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are iid random variables with PDF
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{-2}&\text{if }x\geq1\\0&\text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Let $M_n=\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$. Show that $M_n/n$ converges in distribution, and identify the CDF of the limiting distribution.

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$ The independence of the random variables implies that
$$\begin{align*}\mathsf P(M_n\leq nx)&=\mathsf P(X_1\leq nx)^n\\&=\left(\int_{1}^{nx}\frac{1}{y^2}dy\right)^{n}\\&=\left(1-\frac{1}{nx}\right)^{n}
\end{align*}$$
for all $x$ such that $nx>1$. The above converges to $\large e^{-x^{-1}}$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore I conclude that the CDF of the limiting distribution is given by
$$\mathsf F(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-x^{-1}}&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Therere the PDf is given by
$$\mathsf f_1(x)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{e^{-x^{-1}}}{x^2}&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Then I compute that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathsf f_1(x)dx=1.$$
The proposed CDF gives an appropriate PDF, however I think I made a mistake in taking $x>0$ and hence in the overall calculation.

Is my reasoning above correct?

Thank you for your time and any feedback provided is much appreciated.

Comment: the PDF does not integrate to 1

Comment: @Cettt I added the PDF I get, and I checked the integrationa and it yields 1. But I most likely have a mistake on my PDF then, please correct me I am wrong in my reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation is fine. If you feel uncomfortable for introducing the condition $x > 0$, it may help to utilize the indicator notation $\mathbf{1}(\cdots)$, which is defined as

$$ \mathbf{1}(\cdots) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if $\cdots$ holds}; \\
0, &\text{if $\cdots$ does not hold}.
\end{cases} $$

Using this, we have $f(x) = x^{-2}\mathbf{1}(x \geq 1)$, and so,

$$ \mathsf{P}(X \leq x)
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
= \int_{-\infty}^{x} t^{-2}\mathbf{1}(t \geq 1) \, \mathrm{d}t
= (1 - x^{-1}) \mathbf{1}(x \geq 1). $$

Then it follows that

$$ \mathsf{P}(M_n/n \leq x)
= \mathsf{P}(X_1 \leq nx)^n
= \left(1 - \frac{1}{nx}\right)^n \mathbf{1}(x \geq 1/n)
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^{-1/x} \mathbf{1}(x > 0). $$

This naturally produces the range of $x$ for which the limiting CDF coincides $e^{-1/x}$.